# Как проверять слова Русского языка?

Tags: разработка-игр, поиск, любой-язык, словари

Для игры типа «Эрудита» надо проверять, есть ли составленное игроком слово в словаре, и соответствует ли оно требованиям: именительный падеж, единственное число.

Наверное, достаточно раздобыть текстовый файл со словами через разделитель, и в нём искать. Кстати, может, есть некий формат, более удобный для поиска? Дерево, сортировка, всё такое?

Основной вопрос — **как расширить набор правил?** Разрешить, например, все падежи, множественное число, глаголы во всех временах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- На мой взгляд, какого-то лёгкого или средней сложности способа вы врядли найдёте. Разве что, пропишите все возможные варианты в БД или файле.
- С падежами - проще. Можно было бы прописать корни слов и отдельно возможные суфиксы, окончания слов и т.д. Но и тут засада. Возьмём для примера слова "хэшкод" и "конь". Как проверить правильность написанных слов, если в дательном падеже первое слово будет "хэшкод**У**", а второе - "кон**Ю**"? Вопрос риторический.
- С глаголами и их временами ещё печальней. Берём: "ехать" и "идти". В неопределенном времени (1-е лицо) получаем "езжу" и "хожу". Тут даже логики не просматривается.

Вывод: "**Велик и могуч русский язык, но под PHP не заточен**".

P.S. Кстати, тут неподалеку есть [еще один форум (Русский язык)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/). Возможно, что там могут кое-что дельное подсказать.

Comment: в таком случае «лёгким» способом было бы купить компонент проверки орфографии в самой легкой версии, видимо.

Да, PHP вовсе не критерий. Скорее всего, это будет JS или ActionScript решение на стороне клиента.

Comment: Нашел [такой вариант](http://www.speakrus.ru/dict/#lopatin ) - смотрите "**Орфографический словарь п/р проф. Лопатина (2000 год)**", там есть [Полный вариант для загрузки в БД (2,0 Мб)](http://www.speakrus.ru/dict/lop1v2.zip)

Comment: @sergiks, думаю на стороне клиента не получится. Только если кэш какой-нибудь держать. 

Реально Вам наверное лучше найти словарь так называемых "словоформ" и искать в нем, не занимаясь разбором слов.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю стоит конвертировать словарь в отдельную SQL таблицу для каждой части речи:

Например для имен существительных могут быть такие поля:

```
ID, Приставка, Корень, Суффикс, Окончание, Падеж, Род, Все слово, Одушевлённость, Число(единственное множественнно),Склонение, Нарицательность, Это же слово по умолчанию(ед число именительный падеж)
```

И далее просто делать SELECT к этой таблице.

Другой вопрос как получить эту таблицу из текстового файла, придется писать очень нетривиальный парсер учитывающий морфологию.

Comment: Это смелый способ. С напильником на скалу!